# Extracting IDs from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder if anyone could help with this. I am dynamically building a
form with numbered text fields like:

`<input name='product_quantity_<%= product.id %>' />`

This produces params like: product_quantity_1, product_quantity_4,
etc. I was thinking that I could access these parameters like
param[:product_quantity_#{product.id}] but this doesn't work. How can
I get the parameters dynamically? I hope I've asked this in the right
way.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the split function to get the id, although it's not an elegant solution:

```
ids = {}

for k in param.keys
  ids[k.split('_').last] => param[k]
end
```

This will give you a hash "ids" with all the id's and respective values.

Answer (score 1):

Соuldn't you use names like `"product_quantity[#{id}]"`? They will automatically become an array in Rails.

Comment: this would be a more elegant solution but it depends on how you wish your form to work